# How to insert data in a table from two not-connected tables SQL ORACLE?

Tags: sql, oracle, insert

I am working with a Data Base with 3 tables:

```
CREATE TABLE SALE_DETAIL
( S_SALE NUMBER, 
  S_NUMBER NUMBER, 
  S_ARTICLE VARCHAR2(30), 
  S_COUNT NUMBER
);  
CREATE TABLE SALE
( SALE_ID NUMBER, 
  SALE_COMPANY VARCHAR2(30)
); 
CREATE TABLE SELL
( SELL_ARTICLE VARCHAR2(30), 
  SELL_COUNT NUMBER
);
```

SALE and SELL are tables not connected to each other and they had some data and SALE_DETAIL is empty:

```
INSERT INTO SALE (SALE_ID, SALE_COMPANY) VALUES (1, 'Company1');
INSERT INTO SALE (SALE_ID, SALE_COMPANY) VALUES (2, 'Company1');
INSERT INTO SALE (SALE_ID, SALE_COMPANY) VALUES (3, 'Company2');
INSERT INTO SALE (SALE_ID, SALE_COMPANY) VALUES (4, 'Company3');
INSERT INTO SALE (SALE_ID, SALE_COMPANY) VALUES (5, 'Company2');

INSERT INTO SELL (SELL_ARTICLE,SELL_COUNT) VALUES ('ART1', 100);
INSERT INTO SELL (SELL_ARTICLE,SELL_COUNT) VALUES ('ART2', 50);
INSERT INTO SELL (SELL_ARTICLE,SELL_COUNT) VALUES ('ART1', 100);
INSERT INTO SELL (SELL_ARTICLE,SELL_COUNT) VALUES ('ART3', 200);
INSERT INTO SELL (SELL_ARTICLE,SELL_COUNT) VALUES ('ART3', 100);
```

I would like to fill SALE_DETAIL TABLE with data from SALE and SELL table which are not connected to each other.

```
  S_SALE = SALE_ID --taken from SALE table

  S_NUMBER = ROWID (sequential number starting from 1)   

  S_ARTICLE = SELL_ARTICLE -- taken from SELL table

  S_COUNT = SELL_COUNT  -- taken from SELL table
```

If SALE and SELL table were connected ...I tried this code

```
INSERT INTO SALE_DETAIL(S_SALE,S_NUMBER,S_ARTICLE,S_COUNT)
SELECT s.SALE_ID, ROWID, d.SELL_ARTICLE, d.SELL_COUNT FROM SALE s JOIN SELL d
ON (here I could code the connection beetween tha tables)
```

but How can I do it if they are not connected?

Comment: How many rows do you want to produce? 5 (one from each side) or 25 (all possible combinations).

Answer (score 1):

Join them *virtually*. How? For example, using `row_number` function, you can create a common column which is then used in join. Something like this:

```
SQL> insert into sale_detail (s_sale, s_number, s_article, s_count)
  2  with
  3  t_sale as
  4    (select sale_id,
  5            row_number() over (order by sale_id) rn
  6     from sale),
  7  t_sell as
  8    (select sell_article,
  9            sell_count,
 10            row_number() over (order by rowid) rn
 11     from sell)
 12  select a.sale_id,
 13         a.rn,
 14         e.sell_article,
 15         e.sell_count
 16  from t_sale a join t_sell e on e.rn = a.rn;

5 rows created.
```

Result:

```
SQL> select * from sale_detail;

    S_SALE   S_NUMBER S_ARTICLE                         S_COUNT
---------- ---------- ------------------------------ ----------
         1          1 ART1                                  100
         2          2 ART2                                   50
         3          3 ART1                                  100
         4          4 ART3                                  200
         5          5 ART3                                  100

SQL>
```

---

If number of rows in `sale` and `sell` tables isn't equal, then use outer join (you'll first have to find which table has more rows so that you'd know what to do).